# python monitoring over serial port

Tags: python, pyserial

Good afternoon,

I would ask some suggestion about the best way to monitor events over the serial port.

I'm using PySerial to write "commands" over the serial port towards some devices and

I would like to receive feedback about the status of this devices.

Wich is the best way: 1) fullfill a pipe and read into, 2) a new thread delegated to read only, or what?

Can I also ask for a simple code to implement the solution?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+serial+port

Comment: Sorry but looking into search suggested I couldn't find something helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general tips on working with pyserial, look at the search S.Lott suggested in the comment.

Regarding the best strategy to implement your application - it all depends on how your protocols are defined. Do the devices immediately respond to queries? Or do they continually send data that must be monitored? This is important to define, as it certainly affects the way you'll want to handle the communication.

Generally, I've found it simple and stable to have a separate thread reading everything from the serial port and just pumping the data into a `Queue`. The main application logic then can query this queue whenever it needs to and read the data.

Comment: Yes devices respond immediately, but sometimes it's possible they send data "randomically".
Anyway the search search suggested by S.Lott wasn't helpfull unfortunatelly

Comment: What about the separate thread solution I suggested in the last paragraph? Would it work for you? It's a very general pattern that provides good performance.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy choosen is to use python multiprocessing and queue
see:

1. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/index.html
   and
2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-multiprocessing/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw9dPython-Multi&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grsitelnxw9d

for reference

Comment: Just curious - why did you decide multiprocessing instead of threading?

Comment: Did you use a different process for the reader and the writer?  If so, how did you access the same serial port from different processes?

Comment: Try to take a look to XMLRPC + Python solutions about that. There is the keypoint!